# Ошибка при создании бина JpaRepository в Spring boot приложении

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Пишу приложение Spring Boot, которое взаимодействует с базой данных, при попытке запуска выдаёт ошибку

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'languageRepository' defined in
> com.example.demo.repos.LanguageRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot
> resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean
> property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
> service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Ошибка возникает при использовании версии spring boot 2.3.3.RELEASE. Если же я использую версию 2.1.6, то всё ок. В чём загвоздка?

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

LanguageRepository.java:

```
package com.example.demo.repos;

import com.example.demo.domain.Language;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface LanguageRepository extends JpaRepository<Language, Long> {
    Language findByNameLanguage(String name);
    List<Language> findByInformationProductsNotEmpty();
}
```

Language.java:

```
package com.example.demo.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "language")
public class Language {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_language")
    private Long idLanguage;

    @Column(nullable = false, name="name_language", unique = true)
    private String nameLanguage;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "language", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<InformationProduct> informationProducts;

    public Language() {
    }

    public Language(String nameLanguage) {
        this.nameLanguage = nameLanguage;
    }

    // геттеры и сеттеры
    public Long getIdLanguage() {
        return idLanguage;
    }

    public void setIdLanguage(Long idLanguage) {
        this.idLanguage = idLanguage;
    }

    public String getNameLanguage() {
        return nameLanguage;
    }

    public void setNameLanguage(String nameLanguage) {
        this.nameLanguage = nameLanguage;
    }

    public List<InformationProduct> getInformationProducts() {
        return informationProducts;
    }

    public void setInformationProducts(List<InformationProduct> informationProducts) {
        this.informationProducts = informationProducts;
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:postgres}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:123}
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.freemarker.expose-request-attributes=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

Comment: Поставьте аннотацию - @Repository на LanguageRepository

Comment: @AlekseiGaile, поставил, ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл ответ, оказывается, нужно было добавить следующую строчку в application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```